# Are class methods appropriate when calling functions/methods within the same class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Are class methods appropriate when calling functions/methods within the same class?  Not sure if I am breaking rules or common practices with this approach.  Example:

```
class Tools:

    @classmethod
    def method_one(cls, foo, bar):
        number = foo + bar
        msg = cls.method_two(number)
        print(msg)

    @staticmethod
    def method_two(num_num):
        return f'{num_num} is the magic number'
```

Comment: Why wouldn't they be? You'll only be able to access static and class methods, not instance methods.

Comment: This isn't a great example, as there's no reason for either of these methods (as shown) to be methods at all. `method_two` could be a regular function, and if it is, then `method_one` could be as well.